# Why is my Function Not Working When it Passes the If Statement?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm unsure as to why my function is not working when it goes through the 'if' statement. It works fine otherwise. Here it is:

```
def getwidth():
width = int(input('Enter the Yard Width in Feet: '))
if (width <= 0):
    print()
    print('Error: You Entered a Yard Width of ' + str(width) + ' Which is Invalid - Try Again')
    width = None
    getwidth()
return width
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that you're doing a recursive procedure? is this intentional? Also: you need to fix the indentation in your function.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  "Not working" is not a problem specification.

Comment: if getwidth is returning something you should capture it in width=getwidth() for recursion else you will be getting none

Comment: Yes, the recursion is intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems with your code are that you forgot to return the value of the recursive call, and that the code isn't properly indented. Also there's no need to assign `None` to the local variable, it has no effect because when you do a new function call the value is reset anyway. This should fix the issues, I took the liberty of tidying up the code a bit:

```
def getwidth():
    width = int(input('Enter the yard width in feet: '))
    if width <= 0:
        print('\nError: you entered a yard width of ' + str(width) + ' which is invalid - try again')
        return getwidth()
    return width
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you! I feel so silly right now, haha

Answer (score 0):

Python is sensitive to whitespace, specifically indentation. Try something like this:

```py
def getwidth():
  width = int(input('Enter the Yard Width in Feet: '))
  if (width <= 0):
     print()
     print('Error: You Entered a Yard Width of ' + str(width) + ' Which is Invalid - Try Again')
     width = None
     return getwidth()
  return width
```